# how to properly compare two values from strtotime

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to prevent a user from cancelling a booking if the booking is less than 2 days away. I tried doing this by getting the current date and the date of the booking, converting them both to strtotime and then checking if  one value was greater than the other. However when I run my code though all it does is redirect to page which only displays the value of $diff

Here is my code

```
<?php
$customerRef = $_SESSION['customerRef'];
$messageCancelError;
$messageSuccess;
if (isset($_POST['Cancel'])) 
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
        $cancelAppointment = $_POST['cancel'];
        //echo $cancelAppointment;
        $sql4 = "SELECT dateOfBooking FROM booking WHERE bookingRef=? AND customerRef=?";
        // initalise the prepared statement
        $stmt4 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        // prepare the prepared statement
        if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt4, $sql4)) 
        {
            // bind values to the prepared statement
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt4, "ss", $cancelAppointment, $customerRef);
            // execute the prepared statement
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt4);
            // store the results of the prepared statement
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt4);
            // bind the results of the prepared statement to variables
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt4, $appointmentDate);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt4);
            //echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt4);
            //gets the current date in y-m-d format
            $date = date('Y-m-d'); //gets the difference in todays date and the date of an appointment in seconds
            $diff = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($appointmentDate)); echo $diff; 
        }
        $stmt4->close();
    }
    $stmt4->close();

    //172800 seconds in 2 days
    if ($diff > 172800) 
    {
        // checking for customer ref as well to prevent a user cancelling another users booking
        $sql3 = "DELETE FROM  booking WHERE bookingRef =? AND customerRef =?";
        $stmt3 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt3, $sql3)) 
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt3, "si", $cancelAppointment, $customerRef);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt3);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt3);
            // echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt3);
        }
        if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt3) === 1) 
        {
            $messageSuccess = "Booking Cancelled";
        }
        else 
        {
            $messageCancelError = "Couldn't cancel your booking, check your booking ref against existing ones ";
        }
    }
    // Close statement
    $stmt3->close();
    // Close connection
    // $conn->close();
}
```

I have tried changing it to this but the error is still happening

```
   if ($diff > 172800) {

        // checking for customer ref as well to prevent a user cancelling another users booking
        $sql3 = "DELETE FROM  booking WHERE bookingRef =? AND customerRef =?";
        $stmt3 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt3, $sql3)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt3, "si", $cancelAppointment, $customerRef);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt3);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt3);

            // echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt3);

        if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt3) === 1) {
            $messageSuccess = "Booking Cancelled";
        }//affected rows
        }//stmt_prepare
        }//$diff
        else {
            $messageCancelError = "Couldn't cancel your booking, check your booking ref against existing ones ";
        }
```

Comment: When you echo `$diff`, what is it?

Comment: You don't have anything in the code that would cause a redirect, and you also only have one `echo` statement, so that's why you're seeing the value of `$diff`. What would you expect to happen instead, and why? Also, relying on the number of seconds to calculate dates **will** bite you in the bum someday. Use DateTime objects and save yourself a world of pain.

Comment: You have a closing brace after echo'ing `$diff`

Comment: @Ice76 $diff is the time in seconds between the two dates so if the difference is 2 days diff will echo 172800

Comment: @Mike I am expecting if the time is less than 172800 seconds to skip the delete statement and display the error message which doesnt happen. Instead it just echoes the value for $diff with nothing else appearing on the page

Comment: @Ice76 i tried removing the bracket but it's not made a difference

Comment: Please tell us what the actual value of `$diff` is instead of what you want it to be. I want to know the value of `$appointmentDate`

Comment: @Ice76 $diff = 86,400. any time i have tried this it fails if $diff is < 172,800 and succeeds if $diff is >  172,800

Comment: @RubadubDub is it "86,400", the STRING, or, an INT, 86400. Please be specific as it matters in code and for us to help you. What is the expected output when `$diff` is < 172800

Comment: @Ice76 sorry my mistake i just put the comma in "86,400" out of habit, im kinda in auto pilot mode atm. its an int 86400. Expected output when $diff is < 172800 is $messageCancelError = "Couldn't cancel your booking, check your booking ref against existing ones ";

Comment: @RubadubDub You conditional statements are not in order. I will set the proper order for you in the answer, but this would be a clear example of code readability for others and yourself. Also, for next time, add the intended output or result in the question so we can figure it out quicker!

Answer (score 0):

Your if block needs to change.

Change:

```
//172800 seconds in 2 days
    if ($diff > 172800) 
    {
        ...
        if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt3) === 1) 
        {
            $messageSuccess = "Booking Cancelled";
        }
        else 
        {
            $messageCancelError = "Couldn't cancel your booking, check your booking ref against existing ones ";
        }
    }
    // Close statement
```

To:

```
//172800 seconds in 2 days
if ($diff > 172800)
{
    ...
    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt3) === 1)
    {
        $messageSuccess = "Booking Cancelled";
    }
}
else
{
    $messageCancelError = "Couldn't cancel your booking, check your booking ref against existing ones ";
}
// Close statement
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm still not having any luck, I updated the original post with the code that i changed.

Comment: What output do you get? @RubadubDub

Comment: 86400 the same as before